# Altering screenshot filename

Tags: macos, mac-mini, filesystem, screen-capture

When taking a screenshot using the keyboard shortcut `shift+command+3` it yields a screenshot with a filename of `Screen Shot 2014-11-23 at 3.25.36 PM.png`. I would like to make a change so that the filename would be `scr-20141123-152536.png`. This would be the same exact date and time but altered to what I have been using for the past 13 years on other systems - it just works better for me. Is it possible to make this a permanent change? And, if so, how would I make this change?

UPDATE: I don't want to install Macports or Homebrew, or other package management system or apps that require the user to disable system security in order to run.

My system: Mac mini, late 2012, OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite)

Comment: I'm wondering if this couldn't be accomplished with either an Automator or AppleScript event triggered by a Folder Actions for the Desktop folder?

Comment: douggro, Thanks for mentioning Automator and Folder Actions, I've looked into it and it seems to be the best option so far.

Comment: Mac ports does not require you to reduce system security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that's forward compatible and will not get overwritten in an OSX update is to create a script that does `ls -l Screen*.png` (on the correct directory of course, I'm writing generically) if the list is empty the script exits, if not it uses mv to rename the file (and optionally move it if you also want to, you wouldn't need to since the renamed files won't match `Screen*.png` (the next time the script runs that is).  I would look at using an `xargs` to pipe the `ls` to `mv`. (I'll admit this would take me a minute to cook up, but it's do-able.)

Once you have the script working correctly use `cron` on a one minute schedule (hint `* * * * *`).  Since most of the time the script will exit after one command this will not use any measurable resources.

**Previous answer:**

One option would be to use [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) to rename screenshot files as they are created.  This option really has the most forward compatibility as well.

`fswatch` as the name implies allows you to *WATCH* for *File System* changes within a script, and then pipe the output to some other command.   In this case probably `xargs` calling `mv` to change the name the way you want it to read.

I would reccomend this type of solution, as it is more update proof that modifying the way OSX names the file.  (i.e. that is let OSX do it's thing, then just have a script that watches and renames immediately).

Comment: My apologies, I should have specified that I don't want to install Macports or Homebrew. I've edited the original question to reflect this. I'm wondering if an Automator script would suffice.

Comment: I tried to use Deeper, but it wouldn't run due to being from an unidentified developer - I'm not comfortable disabling system security just to run one allegedly safe app.

Comment: I wouldn't either, let me google around and see if I can edit my answer, there is another method I just can't remember it straight up

Comment: Thank you, Tyson, a bash script and cronjob works great! I have found that this can also be accomplished via an Automator script and Folder Actions.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23001/deeper works to change destination and filename where you want your screenshot to be saved as. Works with Yosemite. Dead simple.

Answer (score 0):

Onyx lets you change the filename of screenshots.

Comment: I tried OnyX, but it requires the user to disable system security in order to run the app. I'm not comfortable with disabling system security.

Comment: Like any other application installation, it requires you to authenticate.  It's pretty much impossible to find any application which will run or install without asking the user to authenticate.  If you don't care for it, thank Avie Tevanian.

Answer (score -2):

Yes if you don't like OnyX, then give this a app a try, which can be seen on this page: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23001/deeper