# Change Time separator in the Screen Shot filename?

Tags: macos, mac, screen-capture

I managed to change screenshot names executing following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture name -string ""
```

So now file names are like:

```
 2018-03-21 at 10.23.08 PM.png
```

I would prefer instead:

```
 2018-03-21 at 10:23:08 PM.png
```

or:

```
 2018-03-21 10:23:08 PM.png
```

or:

```
 2018-03-21 22:23:08.png
```

Is it possible to change it?

Comment: also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157864/altering-screenshot-filename?rq=1